# First Order Central Divided Difference

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Show that the first-order central divided difference is given by:
$$ 
f'(x_i) = \frac{f(X_{i+1}) - f(X_{i-1})}{X_{i+1}-X_{i-1}} + O(h^2)$$
**Note:** Please explain in the simplest way possible, I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor formula? Insert $x_{i+1}=x_i+h$ in a suitable way.

Comment: @OluwatobilolaOni Don't take this in a bad way, but the proper place to start studying a subject is in a book, course notes, or by attending classes. What you are asking will be among the first formulas presented and demonstrated in any finite difference text. If you are willing to run some calculations, the suggestion by Lutz Lehmann will do the trick.